# npm install babel -g network failure

Tags: reactjs, npm, npm-install, jsx

I am unable to install react packages through npm. this is the error I am getting while I am trying to install any package.

My `.npmrc` file is fine. 
`npm config edit`
I checked proxy and port details and everything is fine..

```
C:\Users\admin\loginform>npm install babel --save


npm ERR! code EPROTO
npm ERR! errno EPROTO
npm ERR! request to http://registry.npmjs.org/babel failed, reason: write EPROTO 101057795:error:140770FC:SSL routines:SSL23_GET_SERVER_HELLO:unknown protocol:openssl\
npm ERR!
npm ERR! A complete log of this run can be found in:
npm ERR!     C:\Users\admin\AppData\Roaming\npm-cache\_logs\2017-07-25T07_25_12_574Z-debug.log
```

Comment: Could you please add the output of the npm-debug.log file?

Comment: actually its a network issue but I am not understanding why its coming.

Comment: if you try to open [this](http://registry.npmjs.org/babel) in your browser, do you see a JSON? IF so then the problem might be with your NPM in any case in here https://babeljs.io/ it looks like they have no `babel` package

Comment: only package.json was created. I was unable to install  next packages

Comment: Sounds obvious but I had that issue with failing `npm i` the other day and couldn't get to the bottom of it - restarted my computer and everything worked.

Comment: hahhah @rufio86 , that sounds pretty much like windows behaviour, did that make it for you?